# How FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) works under the hood?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I must develop a Push Notification service like `Firebase Cloud Messaging` service or other similar services. But I don't have any knowledge about this. My questions are:

1. How FCM works under the hood?
2. Does it uses Socket Programming to achieve a Real-Time connection to send a notification?
3. What should I learn to develop a similar service?